# CMake -> MEMORYCHECK_SANITIZER_OPTIONS

Tags: cmake, ctest

What are the allowed values of [MEMORYCHECK_SANITIZER_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_SANITIZER_OPTIONS.html). I've found some examples which seem to add some random options to this variable, e.g.

```
set(MEMORYCHECK_SANITIZER_OPTIONS
    "verbosity=1:symbolize=1:abort_on_error=1:detect_leaks=1")
```

Where are those values documented?

Neither the official documentation nor ctest CLI help offers any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it, they correspond 1:1 to the flags passed to sanitizers: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags